Area of a parallelogram circumscribing an ellipse (proof)
This is my first attempt at a proof. I am trying to make it as rigorous as possible: please point out mistakes or inaccuracies. I have edited it several times to try to make it better and better, agaain, don't hesitate to give advices or corrections. Thank you!
What I had to prove: "Let A and B be the extremes of a diameter of an ellipse. Indicate with r and s the tangents to the ellipse in A and B and with t and u the tangents to the ellipse which are also parallel to the diameter AB. Show that the quadrilateral created with r, s, t, u is a parallelogram and that its area, as AB varies, remains constant."
For reference 
My attempt:
Assume without loss of generality to have the ellipse $$\gamma: \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}= 1 $$
The slope of the tangent line at a given point in the I or II quadrant is: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\bigg) = -\frac{b}{a}\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$
Similarly, the slope of the tangent line for points in III and IV quadrant is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(-\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\bigg) = \frac{b}{a}\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$
Since the diameter passes through the origin and the ellipse is symmetrical about the origin (not really sure if this is correct or if it proves the following) A and B will be symmetrical about the origin, therfore $$x_A = -x_B \Longrightarrow m_r = m_s \Longrightarrow r \parallel s $$ where $m_r$ and $m_s$ are the slopes of r and s. We also have as assumption that $m_t = m_u$. Since the opposite sides are parallel, the quadrilateral has to be a parallelogram.
Now moving to the second part...
under the dilation:
$$
\begin{cases}
x' = \frac{x}{a} \\
y' = \frac{y}{b} \\
\end{cases}
$$ $\gamma$ becomes the circumference $\gamma': x'^2 + y'^2 = 1$. r, s, t and u under the dilation become  r', s', t' and u' and the diameter AB becomes A'B'.

In a circumference a diameter AB is perpendicular to the tangent lines in A and B so t' and u' are orthogonal to r' and s'.
We also have that $r' \parallel s'$ since dilations preserve parallelism. We know that the distance from r' to s' is equal to $2r$ where $r$ is the radius of the circumference...
New part of the proof:
...Under the dilation above the slope of a tangent line is $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(\pm\sqrt{1-x^2})=\mp\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ This short notation shows that the point of tangency between the lines r', s' and $\gamma$ are symmetrical about the origin. Since the origin is the center of $\gamma'$, their distance is the same lenght of the diameter: $2r$.
Old part of the proof:
...and since $t' \parallel u'$ this means that t' has to be perpendicular to "the same radius" as u'. This means that their distance is indeed a straight segment which measures $2r$.
Conclusions:
This proves that the figure created by the tangents is a square (perpendicular sides of same lenght) which has area $S' = 4r^2$, we know that $r = 1 \Longrightarrow S'= 4"$.
A well-known property of dilations is $$\frac{S'}{S}= |hk|$$ In this case $h= \frac{1}{a}$ and $k= \frac{1}{b}$ therfore $$\frac{S'}{S}= \frac{1}{ab} \Longrightarrow S=4ab$$ The area of the parallelogram remains constant and it is equal to $4ab$.
EDIT: Added a new (probabily better) way to prove the area of the figure.

The [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki states that “For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.”

Sorry, I don't understand how this works: how can you tell that the figure after the dilation is a square? By the way, have you found any inaccuracies/mistakes in my proof?

The second half of your work proves the statement that you worked on in the first half.  There is a (non-singular) linear transformation that takes your ellipse to a circle.  The quadrilateral that bounds the circle is a square.  The square has the same area regardless of its orientation.  The reverse transformation takes the square to a parallelogram.  And, the reverse transformation gives the same dilation of area to all objects

@user317176 Well I wanted to construct the proof with very few propositions assumed to be true. Also, I think the second half is still useful because it shows that the side of the square is 2r, a crucial step to calculate S'. Am I missing something?
